# Кнопка первый/последний слайд в slick

Tags: javascript, html, css

Через slick-slider нужно прикрутить кнопку, по нажатию на которую будет показываться первый, либо последний слайд, но я так и не понял как работает индексация и дает ли слик такую возможность

```js
$('.btn').click(
    $('.slider-fisrt').slick('slickGoTo', $('.slick-slide').index(3))
)
```

UPD: Получилось, но он возвращается только к первому слайду, к последнему не хочет, в чем причина?

```js
    $('.slider-first').on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

        console.log(currentSlide);

        if (currentSlide == 0){
            $('.btn').on('click', function () {
                $('.slider-first').slick('slickGoTo', 4, false);
            } 
        )}

        if (currentSlide == 1 || 2 || 3 || 4) {
            $('.btn').on('click', function () {
                $('.slider-first').slick('slickGoTo', 0);
            } 
        )}

    })
```

Comment: Готового функционала нету. Но можно легко сделать, если у тебя не выставлен бесконечный скролл, и ты знаешь количество слайдов

Comment: а для чего нужна проверка на текущий слайд и зачем вешать обработчик внутри afterChange? ну а к первому слайду всегда возвращает, потому что у тебя на одну кнопку два обработчика вешается по условию и последний из них возвращает на первый слайд, так еще эти обработчики дублируются при переключении слайдов) нужно вынести обработчик из afterChange и условия поместить внутрь, а не оборачивать каждый обработчик клика

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let $btn = $('.btn'),
    $slider = $('.slider-first'),
    slideCount = null,
    slideCurrent = 0;

$slider.on('init', function(event, slick) {
  slideCount = slick.slideCount;
});

$slider.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  slideCurrent = currentSlide;
});

$btn.on('click', function() {
  if (slideCurrent == 0) {
    $slider.slick('slickGoTo', slideCount - 1);
  } else {
    $slider.slick('slickGoTo', 0);
  }
});
```